# Can an input array be used to determine the keys on a returned object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that takes an array of possible string values and returns an object that has keys that match the values of the input array. The values of the object properties will be external functions that each have their own type definition so declaring a type for the return object cannot be done from within the function.

See below for an example with the actual and desired types.

```
type Methods = Array<'add' | 'remove' | 'update' | 'get'>;

const createAction = <M extends Methods>(methods: M) => {

    return {
        ...(methods.includes('add') && {
            add: externalAddFunc(),
        }),
        ...(methods.includes('remove') && {
            remove: externalRemoveFunc(),
        }),
        ...(methods.includes('update') && {
            update: externalUpdateFunc(),
        }),
        ...(methods.includes('get') && {
            get: externalGetFunc(),
        }),
    };
    
}

const newAction = createAction(['add', 'remove']);
//  Actual:     newAction: { add?: any; remove?: any; update?: any; get?: any; }  
//  Desired:    newAction: { add: any; remove: any; }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAzlAvFAggJzwEMQAeAckJRTKgB8oy8IBbJANwhvrIFcwVCwTnQYBzeGQB8AbgBQsgMZIAdmmBQFTQRBwLgASxVYoJGFAgAPIcvSx4ydJIAUze6jQAuWAEoskqADe8lAhUEzAPHjKgbKhcVAAdEkubugJ+soKADY8KBBoThRUZL4AZKUx8VVQlChelkJRhFk4VABiPJlO3gA0sdUAvr39VUkJKYju6Zk5eQWMLOycZRVB1fFMrBz1VhBNWQBKixwdXcPrQ33rYxMOaNPZufmFfAJCJVDlleuhr9o7jWUzQAqvxtKcFN0roNztUbq5JmkMo85oVxMAPl81j8QuiAXsgVkAOLwCFQkbxS4UgZyOKyAbyJSqdTKCAAd10BiM2E0EG0nMMyicAG0itQegxNksyABdbxyAD0CriAD0APyyJUhAAi+X0TDqoVZHL0gq8ARqVC8hGUIGkYWOEGttvtDKAA)

Comment: I've updated my answer to allow TypeScript to infer the returned values. My original answer addressed your question as-written and matched your statement of `Desired:    newAction: { add: any; remove: any; }`. If you have different requirements please update your question with more specific information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're determining your actual vs. desired based on hovering over the variable and viewing the structure of the object, if you run this code:

```
type Methods = Array<'add' | 'remove' | 'update' | 'get'>;

const createAction = <M extends Methods>(methods: M) => {

    return {
        ...(methods.includes('add') && {
            add: "externalAddFunc()",
        }),
        ...(methods.includes('remove') && {
            remove: "externalRemoveFunc()",
        }),
        ...(methods.includes('update') && {
            update: "externalUpdateFunc()",
        }),
        ...(methods.includes('get') && {
            get: "externalGetFunc()",
        }),
    };
    
}

const newAction = createAction(['add', 'remove']);
console.log(newAction)
```

you'll see it does have your desired behavior, and logs:

```
[LOG]: {
  "add": "externalAddFunc()",
  "remove": "externalRemoveFunc()"
}
```

NOTE: I did make the external functions strings in order to workaround them not being defined.

Comment: Correct. The return value of `createAction` isn't the problem and is working as expected. It's the type inference that isn't what I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

If you create a mapping between the `Methods` names and your `external*Func` functions then it's possible to update the definition so TypeScript can infer the specific return type for each property.

We can update the signature to then index into that mapping and infer the return type:

```js
{ [K in M[number]]: ReturnType<typeof methodMap[K]> }
```

Here is the full example:

```js
// defining these for the purpose of this example
const externalAddFunc = () => 1 as const;
const externalRemoveFunc = () => (() => {});
const externalUpdateFunc = () => ([] as string[]);
const externalGetFunc = () => ('x');


const methodMap = {
    add: externalAddFunc,
    remove: externalRemoveFunc,
    update: externalUpdateFunc,
    get: externalGetFunc,
};
type MethodNames = keyof typeof methodMap;
type Methods = MethodNames[];

const createAction = <M extends Methods>(methods: M): { [K in M[number]]: ReturnType<typeof methodMap[K]> } => {
    const result = {} as any;
    methods.forEach((method) => {
        if (method in methodMap && method in result){
            result[method] = methodMap[method]();
        }
    });
    return result;
};

const newAction = createAction(['add', 'remove']);
//    ^^ TypeScript can now infer the properties and values
// newAction: {add: 1, remove: () => void}
```

---

**Original answer**

In TypeScript you can refer to the values of an Array constant or tuple by using `TheArrayType[number]`

```js
type Methods = Array<'add' | 'remove' | 'update' | 'get'>;
type Example = Methods[number];
//   ^^^ type Example = "add" | "remove" | "update" | "get"
```

So, to get TypeScript to infer the properties of the returned object, you could use either of these signatures:

```js
const createAction = <M extends Methods>(methods: M): {[K in M[number]]: any} => {
    // ...
}

const newAction = createAction(['add', 'remove']);
/*
newAction: {
    add: any;
    remove: any;
}
*/

const createAction = <M extends Methods>(methods: M): Record<M[number], any> => {
    // ...
}

const newAction = createAction(['add', 'remove']);
/*
newAction: Record<"add" | "remove", any>
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, that won't work, as using `any` collides with the types associated with the external functions I'm using for the values.